# loop inside another loop what is wrong with this code

Tags: c, loops, input, scanf, nested-loops

My input was

```
2
4
```

as I entered `t` as 2, it should run the the loop twice and accept one more integer but it replies

```
return 0
```

I am trying to get many different inputs and running second loop according to them but after first input program `returns 0`. I don't know why; please correct me

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t, i, n, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for (i = 1; i < n; i = i + 2)
        {
            sum = sum + ((n - i + 1) * (n - i + 1));

        }
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please pass your code through [Code beauty](https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier) and update your post.

Comment: Read [ask].  [Edit] your post to include what inputs you have tried and whether it ever output anything.

Comment: thanx did that any more suggestions

Comment: You can't use the same index variable for both loops.  They are stomping on each other.

Comment: You should also check the return value of scanf and fix your format string so that it will consume the end-of-line terminator.

Comment: Create an input fuction: `int GetIntFromUser() {...}` to handle getting user input and verifying that it is valid input.

Comment: the two same index variable were stomping each other